# In Sublime Text3, What is short cut to access top right of the interface?

Tags: sublimetext3

As shown in the attached image ( Sublime.png), What is short cut to open illustrated window and what is name of that window?

I am asking for sublime 3 on windows platform.

[Sublime.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLuSx.png)

Comment: This is an off-topic question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for details.

Comment: @idleberg - I don't think this is off-topic question. As this is a question related to the software tool. And in given link itself, there is a point-like, if a question is related to "software tools commonly used by programmers" then it is a valid question. So kindly check and it and revert back an unreasonable down vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the list of tabs, the shortcut would be "ctrl + k + b" and a side bar would pop up on the left with the list. 
If you want to create a new tab, it would be *ctrl + n* and the name by default would be "untitled"

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need a solution with reference to top-right down arrow window.